# re-initialising DataTable after altering table content

Tags: html, jquery, datatable

I am using `DataTable()` on an already existing HTML `table`

example on the table:

```
<table id="datatable">
<head>
<tr>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test2</th>
<th>test3</th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data7</td>
<td>data8</td>
<td>data9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I then used DataTable on it like this `$("#datatable").DataTable({attributes});`

all working fine till now but when I change table data

```
$("#datatable").DataTable().clear().destroy();
$("#datatable>tbody").html(`
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
</tr>
`);
//data here is shown inside the table
$("#datatable").DataTable({attributes});//when this is executed the data disappears and the table shows:No data available in table
```

Do I have to use `row.add()` after `destroying` the datatable or is there something I am missing

Comment: it turned out that I had another function calling the same destroy and create and that overrides the content I had already added, thanks thus for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't comment so i am writing here.

```
//First Destroy dataTable
$('#dataTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();

//Create new Datatable
$('#dataTable').DataTable({...})
```

```
//In case you are using button click, and button ID is #addRow
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;
 
    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ] ).draw( false );
 
        counter++;
    } );
 
    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
} );
```

Comment: my problem is adding the new data, I can destroy and create but when I am adding data they are discarded

Comment: you are adding new rows using a button click ?